# A question on determinant of a matrix polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-theory

Let

- ${A_j} \in {\mathbb{C}^{n \times n}},0<{w_j}\in \mathbb{R} (j = 0,1,2....m)$ and $\lambda $ is a complex variable such that $\lambda=x+iy$ and  $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$.
- ${\rm{P(}}\lambda {\rm{) = }}{{\rm{A}}_m}{\lambda ^m} + .....{A_1}\lambda  + {A_0}$ is a matrix polynomial.
- ${\rm{Q(}}\lambda {\rm{) = }}{{\rm{w}}_m}{\lambda ^m} + .....{w_1}\lambda  + {w_0}$
- t=$Q{(\left| \lambda  \right|)^2}$

Why does $$D(x,y)=\det (tI - P{(\lambda )^*}P(\lambda )) = \sqrt {{x^2} + {y^2}} p(x,y) + q(x,y)$$ where $p(x, y)$ and $q(x, y)$ are real polynomials in $x, y$?

Furthermore, if $Q(x)$ is even function, then $p(x,y)=0 
$?

Comment: 1) If $t$ is an eigenvalue, shoudn't that determinant be zero? 2) Since you don't say anything about $q(x,y)$ and $p(x,y)$, you are just asking why the determinant is real?

Comment: If $t$ is real, and $P^*P$ is also real, isn't it obvious that the determinant is real?

Comment: The notation is very confusing. Is $p(x,y)$ fixed in advance or is it to be determined to satisfy the equation in your question? What is the relation between $q(x,y)$ and $\mathrm{q}(\lambda)$? Do you distinguish between $q$ and $\mathrm{q}$, or between $w$ and $\mathrm{w}$, etc.? Better not use \rm in math formulas unless you really know what you are doing.

Comment: @IgorKhavkine - I had a mistake before.Fixed it.

Comment: @thedude Let me try to clarify what the question is "obviously" about (@RTMAN correct me if this is wrong): That determinant is obviously a real function of $x$ and $y$ ($D(x,y)$. But functions of the form of a polynomial in the two variables, plus another polynomial times $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, are a rather thin subset of all possible functions. Prove  that $D(x,y)$ is of that form.

Comment: @MarkFischler - Ok, Now let,  if $Q(x)$ is even function, why does $p(x,y)=0 
$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement is false if $P^*$ is taken to mean the element by element complex conjugate of $P(\lambda)$.  A counterexample: let $m=1$, $\omega_0 = \omega_1 = 1$, and
$$A_0 = \left( \begin{array}{cc} 0&i\\2i&0 \end{array} \right) \\
A_1 = \left( \begin{array}{cc} 1&i\\0&2 \end{array} \right)
$$
Then coefficients in $p(x,y)$ come out to be complex non-real.

You must have meant $P^\dagger(\lambda)P(\lambda)$, the Hermitian conjugate of the matrix.
With that change:

$t$ is a real polynomial in the variable $\lambda = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.

Proposition 1:
$\forall n \in \Bbb{N} : \lambda^n $ is either a polynomial in $x^2$ and $y^2$ or (if $n$ is odd) $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ times a  polynomial in $x^2$ and $y^2$.

Since all the $\omega_m$ are real, we have by proposition 1 that  $t = Q(|\lambda| = Q(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ is of the form 
$$
t = P_1(x,y) + \sqrt{x^2+y^2}P_2(x,y)
$$
where $P_i(x,y)$ are both real polynomials.

Now for a given set of $A_m$, each element of $P(\lambda)$ is a (possibly complex) polynomial in $(x,y)$.  But each element of $P^\dagger(\lambda)P(\lambda)$ is a real-valued, thus it is a real polynomial in $(x,y)$.

Then each element of $tI - P^\dagger(\lambda)P(\lambda)$ is a real polynomial in $(x,y)$ plus, for diagonal elements, an expression of the form $P_1(x,y) + \sqrt{x^2+y^2}P_2(x,y)$.

So each element of $tI - P^\dagger(\lambda)P(\lambda)$ is of the form $P_1(x,y) + \sqrt{x^2+y^2}P_2(x,y)$

Finally, the determinant of a matrix is a polnomial function of all of its elements.  This brings us home, because any polynomial function of elements of the form $P_1(x,y) + \sqrt{x^2+y^2}P_2(x,y)$ is itself of the form 
$P_3(x,y) + \sqrt{x^2+y^2}P_4(x,y)$.  Identify in your problem $q(x,y)$ with $P_3$ and p(x,y) with $P_4$.

By the way, if only even powers appear in $Q$, then $P_2(x,y) = 0$ since every term ins itself a polynomial in $x^2+y^2)$. Since the off-diagonal elements are also pure polynomials in $x$ and $y$, in that situation, $p(x,y) = 0$.

Comment: Let $Z(x,y) = ({x^2} + {y^2})p{(x,y)^2} - q{(x,y)^2}$. Can we say that $Z(x,y)$ is reduced?

Answer (score 3):

Variable $t$ is a polynomial in $|\lambda|$. The even powers are real polynomials in $x,y$. The odd powers are real polynomials in $x,y$ multiplied by $|\lambda|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. The quantity $P^*P$ also produces real polynomials in $x,y$. The result follows.

Comment: Thank you .Now let,  if $Q(x)$ is even function, why does $p(x,y)=0 
$?

Comment: As I said, the $|\lambda|$ part comes from the odd powers of $Q$.

Comment: - Let $Z(x,y) = ({x^2} + {y^2})p{(x,y)^2} - q{(x,y)^2}$. Can we say that $Z(x,y)$ is reduced?